# Equivalent android.content.BroadcastReceiver in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, broadcastreceiver

I would like to know if there is an equivalent android.content.BroadcastReceiver in Swift.
I would need the same handler like `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`

It is possible ?

Thank you

Ysee

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Swift in order to achieve the same effect you would use the `NSNotificationCenter`. Take a look at this link below for some guidance

http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it is very interesting, can we put a Notification when there is a database modification from  Parse.com ?

Comment: @Maybe1 Of course. You can fire notifications at any time. If my memory serves correctly you can only respond to notifications on the main thread, so make sure if you try to implement anything that you keep this in mind.