# Toast in the background on homescreen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, toast

I want to show the toast message on anywhere in device (App will run in background via ionic plugin). I want to show the toast for the time user will select from the option (like 10ms, 1s, 2s, etc... and this will be handle by the ion toast). My only question is can I show it in background when app is running in background like whatsapp or hike or any other app which is running in background?

I will build this in ionic 4.

Comment: When app in background/ inactive then you need a Broadcast Receiver for Android app showing a Toast or any other thing.  Try this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts, https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: I am not going to develop the app in android. I am going to use ionic 4 and then via CLI I will convert it to the app. So, it is very helpful if you have anything related to the ionic. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: If you want to use only for Android app in ionic framework then you can do native bridge and implement the broadcast receiver. try this : https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/android/custom-code/,       For ios try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397163/equivalent-android-content-broadcastreceiver-in-swift